# Google Chrome Extension Adding iframe from source

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to load myframe.html inside an iframe and attach that iframe to the DOM of the current page. Is this possible, if myframe.html is part of my extension source?

I was thinking something like

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "myframe.html"); //what would be my path here, if this were possible?
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be possible,  use a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) to inject javascript into the page  and then use the [`chrome.extension.getURL()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#extension-files) method to get the correct URL to your file hosted inside your extension